# How to solve pthread_create() failure: EPERM

Tags: ros, dynamixel, roslaunch, robotis

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am attempting to use the ROBOTIS-Manipulator Code in ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04.
It is successfully executing catkin_make but is giving an error in roslaunch. After a lot of time I think that I have figured out that the error is in the following code snippet. I outputted the value of error and as shown below, it is giving 1 => EPERM (No permission to set the scheduling policy and parameters specified in attr). How to solve this error?

Error:

```
[ INFO] [1464938807.597236403]: error: 1
[ERROR] [1464938807.597311436]: timer thread create fail!!
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::lock_error> >'
```

Code Snippet:

```
// create and start the thread
        if((error = pthread_create(&this->timer_thread_, &attr, this->ThreadProc, this))!= 0) {ROS_INFO("error: %d", error);
            ROS_ERROR("timer thread create fail!!");
            exit(-1);
        }
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235984/how-to-solve-pthread_create()-failure:-eperm/) by [RohitM](https://answers.ros.org/users/26985/rohitm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2016-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error is easily solved by running as root. But note that it is not enough to run only the roslaunch command with sudo, you must compile and source as root as well. Not sure why that is but it is running smoothly now.

---

Originally posted by [RohitM](https://answers.ros.org/users/26985/rohitm/) with karma: 115 on 2016-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1